# Android: How to show soft keyboard's suggestion bar

Tags: android

I have a listview with many rows, each row is a edittext. 
When touching on last editext, I want the soft keyboard is shown and not cover my last edittext.

I searched on internet and found that if putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in Manifest.xml would help, and the result correctly like what I want. But when i type some words, soft keyboard's suggestion bar show up and cover the last edittext again.

I don't want to disable the suggestion bar so i wonder is there a way to display full keyboard with suggestion text bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try rather : **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

```
<activity
      android:name="SimpleActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks Jarvis, but adjustResize will put all screen up, if there are more components below my listview like another listview, buttons...Beside it, adjustResize  will make eddittext lost focus.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a bottom margin on your last EditText? I know it sounds dirty, but it may work.

Comment: The keyboard still appear next to the edittext even I used layout_margin or padding